# Installing redcar caused gem issues. Invalid gemspec and

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, redcar

I installed redcar, then installed railsinstaller for my Mac.
I also updated my gems using, noticed things got hairy so ran: `gem update --system`
I am getting the following errors when I type `rails -v` :

```
Invalid gemspec in [/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/specifications/redcar-0.13.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x10f332d08> 1.1.2"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/specifications/redcar-0.13.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x10f332d08> 1.1.2"]
Latest version currently installed. Aborting.
```

How do I fix this? I would like to install rails.

Thank you.

Comment: maybe tell the Redcar people?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this will fix your problem, but it would probably be better if you uninstalled redcar. it IS a rather nice editor in my opinion, but there hasn't been an update for about 11 months and there's still [an unanswered pull request for fixing a bug under mac osx](https://github.com/danlucraft/redcar/pull/16).

(sorry for posting this as an answer, but it appears that i can't write comments (yet).)